# Steps to show live HTTP streaming video with no extension on MPMovieplayercontroller?

Tags: iphone, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller, http-live-streaming, mediastreamsegmenter

I am trying to develop an iPhone app which will be able to show live stream video on iPhone.The link is in format 'http://192.168.111.18:8002/testlink'.
I went through all the apple documentation and have downloaded mediastreamsegmenter and also it has been installed properly as I can see its details using 'man mediastreamsegmenter' command.I couldn't understand it after that.Please guide me regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a link with suffix ".m3u8", which contains the TS segments of the live video stream. When you click on the "m3u8" link, then the video player will be launched to request for those TS segments, otherwise, the browser won't know it is a live video link.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: I tried the link using m3u8 extension and the player couldn't open the file.

Comment: Do you have the testlink.m3u8 file at that position?

Comment: No...It doesn't have one I think...Because the link is given by the client.Can I use something like 'Wowza' as an intermediate server?i.e.I will take the input stream,give it to wowza,which will return .m3u8 file which then I can use for playback..Or any other solution?

Comment: Yes, you can use Wowza as an intermediate server, but the precondition is that Wowza must support your input stream. What's your input stream's format?

Comment: Not sure about whether Wowza can convert wmv to m3u8 or not. Anyway, it's worthy to try...

Comment: Thanks for all the help.Can you guide me how can I use wowza as intermediate server?I know I am questioning a lot but I am trying for 2 days and desperately need it to work..

Comment: The forum of wowza is quite active. I believe you can get what you need in the forum.

Comment: OK...Thanks a lot for your valuable help.

Comment: I couldn't find how to use an intermediate server in my case...Please help!